# How to choose database from which to update Entities?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I just started working on a project that uses Entity framework and it has an `.edmx` file. I've made changes to my development database but when I right-click the designer (*Update Models from Database...*) it retrieves schemas from some random database (can't even see the name of it!?).

How to I choose from which database to retrieve schemas in the `.edmx` designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Right-click* the designer
2. Click **Properties**
3. Under **Connection** you'll find the **Connection String** used by the designer
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and *search for the Connection String*
5. *Edit the Connection String*, save it and reload the designer